# Using CUT (or SED) to remove a column from a text fil

Tags: linux

I'd like some help please, to remove the source port from this list, i.e. so that I only have the client IP address (not the colon and source port number) and server address and port number.

```
client 129.0.0.230:49982 server 10.193.75.71:80
client 129.0.0.230:49983 server 10.193.75.71:80
client 129.0.0.230:49986 server 10.193.75.71:80
client 129.0.0.230:49987 server 10.193.75.71:80
client 129.0.0.230:49989 server 10.193.75.71:80
client 129.0.0.230:49990 server 10.193.75.71:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat test.lst |cut -f1 -d':' && cat test.lst|cut -f3,4 -d' '
```

It will help to fetch only those data you want to fetch.

Comment: there is no need to `cat file | cut ...`, you can directly do `cut ... file`

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/client \|:.*server//g' input.lst
```

The expression says: remove "client " and everything between a colon and "server".

Answer (score 1):

To remove only the ':client-port' column.

```
cat <file> | sed 's/\(.*\)\(:[0-9]\{5\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3/g'
```

OR

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\(:[0-9]\{5\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3/g' <file>
```